# MaxValue and MinValue for RadNumericTextBox does not work at all

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik.Web.UI version v4.0.30319.

The MaxValue and MinValue does not work at all even after setting AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect to false.

The following is the code I have used.

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtMinutes" runat="server" AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" MaxValue="1440" MinValue="0" Width="35px" MaxLength="4">
    <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Also it is accepting negative values

I need it to be validated for onchange event of the RadNumericTextBox but not on lost focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you I understand you correctly, I think you were thinking of a server-side validation. What you can do is to set `AutoPostBack` property to **true** and register a `OnTextChanged` event and do your validation in the code behind.

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtMinutes" runat="server" AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" Width="35px" MaxLength="4">
    <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void txtMinutes_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var val = int.Parse(txtMinutes.Text);
    if (val < 0 || val > 1440)
    {
         // do your thing when out of range...
    }
    else
    {
         // do your thing when within range...
    }
}
```

Please also take a note of the following regarding RadNumericTextBox.

> Use the MaxValue and MinValue properties to specify a range for the
>   numeric text box. If the user tries to enter a value that is greater
>   than the value of the MaxValue property, the numeric text box
>   automatically changes the value to MaxValue. Similarly, if the user
>   tries to enter a value that is less than the value of the MinValue
>   property, the numeric text box automatically changes the value to
>   MinValue.
>
> RadNumericTextBox does not support maximum and minimum
>   values with a greater magnitude than +/- 2^46. Setting the MaxValue
>   property to more than 2^46 or the MinValue property to less than -2^46
>   can cause abnormalities in the RadNumericTextBox behavior.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/input/radnumerictextbox/overview#limiting-the-range

Answer (score 1):

Your Code is working fine at my end. To avoid negative number u can validate Like This

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtMinutes" runat="server" AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" MaxValue="1440" MinValue="0" Width="35px" MaxLength="4">
    <NumberFormat DecimalDigits="0" />
<ClientEvents OnKeyPress="OnKeyPress" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
 function OnKeyPress(Sender, args) {
        if (args.get_keyCode() == 45`enter code here`) {
            alert("-ve number is not allowed!");
            args.set_cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate a range for RadNumericTextbox you need to use `RangeValidator` like:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="NumericTextBoxRangeValidator" 
                runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtMinutes"
                ErrorMessage="Please enter in a number between 0 and 100." 
                Display="Dynamic"
                MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="0" Type="Decimal">
```

[Telerik example/documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/textbox/functionality/validation/defaultcs.aspx)

Hope this helps!